¿How to get OpenId userinfo claims?
I have this method in the controller to get user in the frontend:
@GetMapping("/user")
public Mono<Map<String, Object>> getOidcUserPrincipal(Mono<Principal> principal) {
    return principal.filter(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class::isInstance).cast(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)
            .map(OAuth2AuthenticationToken::getPrincipal).filter(OidcUser.class::isInstance).cast(OidcUser.class)
            .map(OidcUser::getClaims).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new InvalidSessionException()));
}

with this configuration:
spring:
security:
    user:
        name: ...
        password: ...
    oauth2:
        client:
            registration:
                example:
                    provider: example
                    client-id: ....
                    client-secret: .....
                    client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
                    authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                    redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
                    scope:
                        - openid
                        - email
                        - profile
            provider:
                example:
                    jwk-set-uri: http.../jwks
                    token-uri: http.../token
                    authorization-uri: http.../auth
                    user-info-uri: http.../userinfo
                    user-info-authentication-method: query
                    user-name-attribute: sub

the line "OidcUser::getClaims" is supossed to request userinfo endpoint, but it doesn't, I'm just getting the information from the id_token. Users can login and the access token is saved fine.
I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent:3.3.2 and spring-cloud.version:2023.0.0, but it also breaks with 3.0.4 and 2022.0.2 respectively. This works for previous cloud.version:2021 and spring-security 5. What I'm missing?
